# What is Gitkraken's default git-config esp. for gitflow

Tags: git, git-flow, git-config, gitkraken

Gitkraken does not follow the default Git settings. When I use *git* and *git flow* from the command line, the operations taken are different from what Gitkraken performs.  On the command line, doing `git merge` by default does a fast forward.  Gitkraken does not fast-forward when merging.  When using *git flow* from the command line, finishing a feature also does a fast forward by default.  When finishing a hotfix, if *nobackmerge* is false and *notag* is true, gitflow will merge master into develop, which seems at odds with the git flow workflow.  This does not happen in Gitkraken when a hotfix is not tagged.  I looked through Gitkran's *.gitkraken* directory and could not find any git settings.  I also looked in the *.gitconfig* directories where I used Gitkraken, hoping to find what settings it uses.  It appears Gitkraken passes built-in default arguments to the git commands that it runs without disclosing it, and ignoring any user Git settings. So far, by using *git flow* on the command line and Gitkraken in separate directories, and then looking at the *git reflog*, I've been able to find that these settings are being emulated:

```
[merge]
    ff = false
[pull]
    ff = true
[gitflow]
    multi-hotfix = true
[gitflow "hotfix.finish"]
    nobackmerge = true
    no-ff = true
[gitflow "feature.finish"]
    no-ff = true
```

These options are selected interactively

```
[gitflow "hotfix.finish"]
    notag = true|false
    keep = true|false
[gitflow "feature.finish"]
    notag = true|false
    keep = true|false
```

I am trying to set up .gitconfig so that command line Git's default behavior approximates Gitkraken's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I've used GitKraken's git flow for years.  However, i lately sometimes need to ssh into my machine and develop via say nvim. That said, I was hoping to solve this as well.
I found this good read that pushes trunk but documents git flow and includes a suggestion for a gitflow package (mac and windows).
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
I'm investigating, since I like gitflow for a small team and even for projects of one where you come back to a project for work over time.
Examining brew info git-flow lead to an old package and listed a conflicting related one. Perhaps the best thing to do is read the updated original post that started it all https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
There is enough description there to practice the git flow using the steps described there. I think that's what I'm going to do because I use "main" vs "master" branch name and I'd like to switch between the command line and GitKraken use when on my main machine.
I hope this helps answer your question. Additionally, I believe GitKraken uses Nodegit but I see here an [experimental feature](https://www.gitkraken.com/blog/gitkraken-client-9-4#welcome-to-our-laboratory) to start using a specified git executable. Perhaps enabling that and examining it as you did above might reveal the config? Please post your learnings if you would be so kind. I hope this helps.